# pytest ScopeMismatch exception

Tags: pytest

I am trying to create integration tests using pytest framework. I am grouping all the tests for a feature under common class and want to setup some test data before executing test cases. I am trying to do this using a fixture with class scope, this fixture would invoke db and perform some setup required for this feature. For this class level fixture, I pass another fixture(session for accessing db) with scope of function. When I try to do this, I get ScopeMismatch error. I understand this is not allowed in pytest, is there a better was of accessing the db without changing the scope of session fixture or other ways to implement this test scenario.

```
conftest.py
@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def connection(engine):
    connection = engine.connect()
    yield connection
    connection.close()


@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def session(connection):
    transaction = connection.begin()
    session = Session(bind=connection)
    yield session
    session.close()
    transaction.commit()

test_feature.py

@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def prepare_test_data(session):
    rs = session.execute("select user from user limit 10")
    # update test data files/ db tables

@pytest.mark.usefixtures('prepare_test_data')
class TestNodeListResource:
```

Comment: In your code, you create a new db session for each test function, but then you try to write a (test) session-based fixture based on that (db) session - this cannot work in principle, the session fixture is executed before any test. I'm not sure what you want to achieve here.

Comment: You should probably change the scope of `prepare_test_data` to 'function' so it can use the fixture `session`.

Comment: If i change the scope of prepare_test_data fixture to session, the fixture prepare_test_data gets executed for every test in class TestNodeListResource which i want to avioid.